# Rewrite Apache session cookie to append 'expires' attribute

Tags: apache, internet-explorer, session, cookies

I'm using Apache as a reverse proxy with forms authentication.
Using SessionMaxAge I can set the cookie to expire after 24 hours.
This renders the 'max-age' attribute into the cookie.
Unfortunately Internet Explorer only accepts the 'expires' attribute.

Is there a way to, for example, rewrite the cookie before sending it the client?

Thanks in advance.

Kind regards,
Kevin

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to edit both request and response headers using [the `header` directive in mod_headers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_headers.html#header)

The best approach would probably be to use `Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;Expires.....` However, mod_headers can't do the actual Expires sting itself (it doesn't know how to produce that date format), so you will have to actually put that inside the original cookie or another header, then grab it from there and put it into the `Header` directive. It's quite complicated, but it is possible.

Comment: Nevermind, I switched to Nginx. I can use a piece of Lua script to insert the correctly formatted date string.